# Why doesn't PartialLeastSquaresAnalysis (in Accord.Statistics.Analysis) have a Save method?

Tags: accord.net

Net users,

How can I persist an instance of the PartialLeastSquaresAnalysis class?  Other classes (e.g. KernelSupportVectorMachine) have a Save method so that we can persist the object to the disk.  Since PartialLeastSquaresAnalysis does not have a Save method, is there another way to persist this classs?

Thanks for your help.

Charles

Answer (score 2):

The save and load methods found in the framework are just convenience methods for the standard .NET binary serialization. If those methods are not available for a particular class, you should still be able to save it using:

```
PartialLeastSquaresAnalysis analysis = ...

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    var fmt = new BinaryFormatter();
    fmt.Serialize(fs, analysis);
}
```

and you should be able to load it back using

```
PartialLeastSquaresAnalysis analysis = null;

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
    var fmt = new BinaryFormatter();
    analysis = (PartialLeastSquaresAnalysis)fmt.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you replace "stream" with "fs"?

Comment: Note: In the current version of the framework, all .Load and .Save methods are now implemented through the project's [Serializer class](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_IO_Serializer.htm). You can use it to save and load any objects and models from the framework.